# View cvs file in mysql within PopSQL

Tags: mysql, popsql

Command line code:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/anishachoudhury/Desktop/Anisha/mysql/school-closures-covid.csv' 
    -> INTO TABLE faceCoverings
    -> IGNORE 1 ROWS;
Query OK
```

PopSQL and mysql database are connected. I have written query for csv file on mysql using command line. How do i show it on popsql? wHat is the line of code?

Comment: the path to the csv file is not accessible to the popsql on your machine

Comment: SELECT * from facecoverings; ?